# Проверка на ввод только символов в строке

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Введите фамилию студента: "); 
String surname = scan.next();
```

Как сделать так, чтобы выполнялась проверка вводимых символов в строке? 
От "А" до "Я" и от "а" до "я". И если встречается символ, отличный от русского, или цифра, то выдается ошибка. Спасибо.

Comment: Не забудьте про дефис в двойных фамилиях. Наверно, в иностранных фамилиях может быть несколько слов через пробел.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
public boolean isAlpha(String name) {
    return name.matches("[а-яА-Я]+");
}
```

Вернёт false, если хотя бы один из символов не буква.

Comment: спасибо, помогло